# How does one recreate (merged) branch that was deleted from local and remote?

Tags: git

After merging a feature branch to development and then deleting the local and remote, I realized I forgot to merge this to the production branch.

When I try to checkout the final commit, I get a warning "Checking out this commit will create a detached HEAD, and you will no longer be on any branch.." so a little apprehensive on that action.

Are there steps to reproduce the feature branch so it can be merged to production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could recreate it in the aggregate through cherry picking.

Create a new branch off of prod. Then cherry-pick the new feature commits from develop and merge that into production.

To do the cherry pick (as mentioned in the comments), you can do one commit at a time with `git cherry-pick <hash>` or you can do a series of commits with `git cherry-pick <startingHash>..<finishingHash>`

Comment: yes. ``git cherry-pick commithash`` http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html